# How to set up an cloudwatch alarm for lambda timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda created via cloudformation template, as such. I have set my memory size and timeout period. I would like to fire off an alarm , if lambda times out. I am know sure what metric name, statistics and other values to set for my alarm below

```
Resources: 
  someLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "MyFunct"
      Description: "..."
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 500
   
 timeoutAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: "timeout"
      AlarmDescription: "Alarm if lambda times out"
      MetricName: ...
      Dimensions:
      - Name: "FunctionName"
        Value: MyFunct
      Statistic: ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no metric for timeouts**. The only way for you to do it is to setup [metric filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringPolicyExamples.html) on your function's logs, to search for timeout messages. Then on you can create an alarm based of such a filter.

Comment: That's just dumb. If Lambda can timeout, and it can, it's a standard behavior, they should offer an alarm type out of the box for it.